# How to create a Mac App launcher for Emacs via HomeBrew?

Tags: emacs, homebrew

I created a Mac App launcher for Emacs installed via Homebrew. The technique uses Automator.

The problem with Automator is that a spinning gear goes into the taskbar each time. I'd rather not have to close it every time I start Emacs!

[image]

[Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS)

> Using Emacs.app from the Dock Create an app that runs a shell script
>   that runs Emacs.app, like this: use Finder to navigate to
>   /Applications and double-click Automator.app. Select the document type
>   “Application” and click “Choose”. In the list on the left, select
>   “Library”. In the next list, find “Run Shell Script” and drag it into
>   the workflow area on the right. In the new shell script, delete the
>   text and replace it with:
>
> cd # Start in my home directory.
>
> ## Use my environment: echo '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"' | bash --login -s
>
> "$@" Select “Shell: /bin/bash” and “Pass input: as arguments”. Click
>   “File > Save…” and choose a name and location for your new app. For
>   example, you might choose the /Applications directory and name the app
>   “Emacs for Dock.” Don’t replace Emacs.app.
>
> If you like, you can change your new app’s icon to match Emacs.app,
>   like this: select Emacs.app and right-click “Get Info” or press cmd+i.
>   In the info window, select the small icon in the top left corner and
>   copy it (cmd+c). Next, select your new application, get its info,
>   select the small icon and paste (cmd+v).
>
> Drag your new app into the Dock as usual, and you’re good to go.
>
> Your new app does two things that the Dock doesn’t (on Mac OS 10.9).
>   The “cd” command causes emacs to start in your home directory, instead
>   of the root directory “/”. The --login option gives emacs the same
>   environment as an interactive Terminal. In particular, it gives emacs
>   your usual PATH environment variable, so you can run commands in emacs
>   the same as commands in Terminal. An alternative to --login is -i,
>   which sets the environment differently, as described in the

Comment: I used Platypus, which has options (when creating the application) to run in background and/or remain running after initial execution.  I also did it with a combination of shell script that runs an applescript.  Line 1:  `#!/bin/sh`  Line 3:  `osascript -e 'tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs_10_01_2014.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate'`  I did this to achieve workaround for a rare bug that affected my dock becoming unhidden on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Is this different than doing `brew linkapps`?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours trying various ways to do this same thing today, and came up with one that only has one negative side effect: It creates an extra icon for the running emacs on the dock (See Screenshots). This has only been tested on Yosemite.

Note: I got this from https://korewanetadesu.com/emacs-on-os-x.html, though I didn't bother with the client/server setup as I don't need it. It seems to setup the environment like your wiki example does as well, as far as I can tell.

[Screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwRXw.jpg)

This is by creating an apple script using Script Editor (found under Applications/Utilities/ for me) containing in your case:

```
tell application "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
```

And then saving it as an application